# Recortar número inteiro, algum modo de fazer?

Tags: php

Estou precisando recortar um valor inteiro para poder usar em minha aplicação, anteriormente o campo era uma string em meu banco e agora está como inteiro, existe algum mode de se fazer isso?
Estava fazendo assim até então, agora me surgiu a necessidade de recortar um número inteiro.

```
$IdUF = substr($rowData['IdMunicipio'],0,2)
```

Ou estou falando alguma besteira?
Preciso de alguma dica.

Comment: `subst` retorna outra `string`, se está retornando o valor devidamente, bastaria converter para `int` com a função `intval` ou adicionar `(int)` na frente da função.

Comment: É como @AndersonCarlosWoss disse. No seu caso, você deve converter o inteiro para uma string usando (string) antes `$IdUF = substr((string)$rowData['IdMunicipio'], 0, 2)`

Comment: Agradeço as dicas, vou fazer alguns testes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PHP não é fortemente tipado

`$IdUF = substr($rowData['IdMunicipio'],0,2)`
 retorna uma string
mas caso `$IdUF` seja usado em uma operação como soma seu valor 
será convertido assim se:

```
<?php
$IdUF = substr($rowData['IdMunicipio'],0,2);
//$IdUF = "10" - Str
//Quando fazemos alguma operação
$IdUF++;
//$IdUF = 11 - Int
```

Agora se o problema é na hora de salvar no banco a solução depende de como você esta implementado.

Uma solução para forçar o valor é realizar o cast ou conversão, entre as soluções você poderia:

```
<?php
$IdUF = (int)substr($rowData['IdMunicipio'],0,2);
//ou
$IdUF = intval(substr($rowData['IdMunicipio'],0,2));
//Dessa forma o $IdUF será sempre inteiro, caso seja retornando 
//um valor que ele não consiga converter como "olá"
// o valor de $IdUF será 0.
```